# apt update NO_PUBKEY

Tags: apt

When I go to `sudo apt update` on my computer, I have recently started to see this error:

```
W: GPG error: http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY CBF8D6FD518E17E1
E: The repository 'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie Release' is not signed
```

And I have no clue why. The full output is:

```
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary bionic InRelease                       
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:6 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic InRelease    
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease        
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease            
Ign:9 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease                 
Hit:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease           
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Get:15 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release [148 kB]         
Hit:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease          
Hit:10 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease               
Get:17 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release.gpg [2,420 B]    
Ign:17 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done  
W: GPG error: http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY CBF8D6FD518E17E1
E: The repository 'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

`apt-key list` output:

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2017-06-22 [SC]
      63C4 6DF0 140D 7389 6142  9F4E 204D D8AE C33A 7AFF
uid           [ unknown] Pop OS (ISO Signing Key) <info@system76.com>
sub   rsa4096 2017-06-22 [E]

pub   rsa2048 2014-08-04 [SC]
      3FA7 E032 8081 BFF6 A14D  A29A A6A1 9B38 D3D8 31EF
uid           [ unknown] Xamarin Public Jenkins (auto-signing) <releng@xamarin.com>
sub   rsa2048 2014-08-04 [E]

pub   rsa4096 2017-12-15 [SCEA]
      0A0F AB86 0D48 5603 32EF  B581 B754 42BB DE9E 3B09
uid           [ unknown] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom (https://packagecloud.io/docs#gpg_signing) <support@packagecloud.io>
sub   rsa4096 2017-12-15 [SEA]

pub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [SC]
      EB4C 1BFD 4F04 2F6D DDCC  EC91 7721 F63B D38B 4796
uid           [ unknown] Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [S] [expires: 2019-04-12]
sub   rsa4096 2017-01-24 [S] [expires: 2020-01-24]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/libregeek-archive-keyring.gpg
----------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2016-11-23 [SC] [expires: 2018-11-20]
      786F ACA9 4AF4 CD9E 43AA  3CC7 05AC DA74 7113 232D
uid           [ unknown] Michael DeGuzis <mdeguzis@gmail.com>
sub   rsa4096 2016-11-23 [E] [expires: 2018-11-20]

pub   rsa4096 2015-09-17 [SC] [expires: 2018-11-20]
      701B E471 7660 229C BDE0  7304 8106 E728 34C5 89A7
uid           [ unknown] SteamOS-Tools Signing Key (SteamOS-Tools repository signing key) <mdeguzis@gmail.com>
sub   rsa4096 2015-09-17 [E] [expires: 2018-11-20]

pub   rsa4096 2016-09-26 [SC] [expired: 2016-12-26]
      9391 5C33 6DCE 6B51 5F5D  7197 BD09 77A6 A44A 79DB
uid           [ expired] Michael DeGuzis (Primary personal key) <mdeguzis@gmail.com>

pub   rsa4096 2016-11-04 [SC] [expires: 2018-11-20]
      D8E3 C58E 3433 8706 3D0A  5D54 440E B49E 5765 5DD5
uid           [ unknown] LibreGeek Signing Key <mdeguzis@gmail.com>
sub   rsa4096 2016-11-04 [E] [expires: 2018-11-20]

pub   rsa2048 2013-12-03 [SC] [expires: 2023-12-01]
      726D 300E A8B6 4874 B32F  1370 3F6E D944 7993 A629
uid           [ unknown] pandajim (key for lives deb) <ubuntuhandbook1@gmail.com>
sub   rsa2048 2013-12-03 [E] [expires: 2023-12-01]

pub   rsa4096 2013-12-10 [SC]
      7482 31EB CBD8 08A1 4F5E  85D2 8C00 4C2F 9348 1F6B
uid           [ unknown] Brent Timothy Saner <brent.saner@gmail.com>
uid           [ unknown] keybase.io/squarer00t <squarer00t@keybase.io>
uid           [ unknown] Brent S. (http://www.square-r00t.net) <bts@square-r00t.net>
uid           [ unknown] r00t^2 (https://sysadministrivia.com) <r00t@sysadministrivia.com>
uid           [ unknown] [jpeg image of size 23396]
sub   rsa4096 2013-12-10 [E]

pub   dsa1024 2004-01-05 [SC]
      C520 48C0 C074 8FEE 227D  47A2 7023 53E0 F7E4 8EDB
uid           [ unknown] Thomas Dickey <dickey@invisible-island.net>
sub   elg1024 2004-01-05 [E]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg
----------------------------------------
pub   rsa2048 2015-10-28 [SC]
      BC52 8686 B50D 79E3 39D3  721C EB3E 94AD BE12 29CF
uid           [ unknown] Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
------------------------------------
pub   rsa2048 2015-10-28 [SC]
      BC52 8686 B50D 79E3 39D3  721C EB3E 94AD BE12 29CF
uid           [ unknown] Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/snwh_ubuntu_ppa.gpg
------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2012-06-27 [SC]
      D320 D0C3 0B02 E64C 5B2B  B274 3766 2239 8999 3A70
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Sam Hewitt

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/system76_ubuntu_pop.gpg
----------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2017-06-19 [SC]
      E6AC 1657 2ED1 AD6F 96C7  EBE0 1E5F 8BBC 5BEB 10AE
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for System76

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-archive.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      790B C727 7767 219C 42C8  6F93 3B4F E6AC C0B2 1F32
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>
```

`apt policy debian-archive-keyring` output:

```
debian-archive-keyring:
  Installed: 2017.7ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2017.7ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2017.7ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`dpkg -L debian-archive-keyring` output:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/debian-archive-keyring
/usr/share/doc/debian-archive-keyring/README
/usr/share/doc/debian-archive-keyring/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/debian-archive-keyring/copyright
/usr/share/keyrings
/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg
/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg
/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg
/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg
/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-removed-keys.gpg
/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-stretch-automatic.gpg
/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-stretch-security-automatic.gpg
/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-stretch-stable.gpg
/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg
/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg
```

Running Pop!_OS 18.04 LTS x86_64

Kernel 4.15.0-23-generic

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `apt-key` setup doesn’t have any of the Debian archive keys, which is why `apt` can’t verify the Debian repositories. Install `debian-archive-keyring` to fix that:

```
sudo apt install debian-archive-keyring
```

Since you’re using the Ubuntu version of the package, you need to link the keyrings:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive*.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
```

Once that’s done, update the repository indexes:

```
sudo apt update
```

The installation will probably complain about not being able to verify the package (and you should tell it to proceed anyway), but the issue should be fixed after the update.